# Panels in Panels in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: html, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am new to Sencha Touch 2 and I want to have something like:

- A list (eg for todos, just for trying out ST2) where I can tap to edit or set it as done etc.

I am not sure I am doing it right, but I am thinking I have a panel containing a list on the left and details view on the right. Looking at the docs for Conatiner:

```
//this is the Panel we'll be adding below
var aboutPanel = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
    html: 'About this app'
});

//this is the Panel we'll be adding to
var mainPanel = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
    fullscreen: true,

    layout: 'hbox',
    defaults: {
        flex: 1
    },

    items: {
        html: 'First Panel',
        style: 'background-color: #5E99CC;'
    }
});

//now we add the first panel inside the second
mainPanel.add(aboutPanel);
```

I figured I might be able to use the `config` property for configure my Panel:

```
Ext.define("SimpleTodo.view.Main", {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    config: {
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                config: {
                    html: 'Panel 1 ...'
                }
            },
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                config: {
                    html: 'Panel 2 ...'
                }
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Fails: A blank screen. If I add `html` property into `config` I get HTML shown but what I am I doing wrong with the `items`?

You might have also noticed, I am having a list of left and details on right. This is good for tablets, but how can I make it for phones? Do I need to use Profiles and separate views for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but what I am I doing wrong with the items?

You don't have a `config` property for `panel` component. So, remove the `config` property for each individual `panel` and directly use `html` property to set html inside each `panel`

Like this,

```
{
  xtype: 'panel',
  html: 'Panel 1 ...'
},
{
  xtype: 'panel',
  html: 'Panel 2 ...'
}
```

Comment: Actually, thats 1 confusion for me. Is `panel` same as `Ext.Panel`? I was thinking they are aliases or something, but if I use Ext.Panel I get an error

Comment: Oh and about `config` and no `config` thing, how do I know if I should add properties to `config: { ... }` or just put it in the object properties?

Comment: `panel` is an xtype (class alias), and `Ext.Panel` is a REAL class

Comment: @ThiemNguyen, so can I say when I use `xtype`, whatever meant to go into `config` should simply be defined inline? Like the `html` property above?

Comment: yes, it's equal to: `Ext.create('Ext.Panel',{html: 'test'});`